# WebView showing blank page

Tags: android, webview

I'm working on a project and i need to show a webpage. But when i try to show it on a device, I get a blank page. If i copy this page and past into the device's browser, i can see it normally. Also, if I run it on a virtual device, i can see the page normally as well on both application and browser. So my problem is at the device. I already have the Internet permission.

EDIT - Worked with another URL(http://www.globo.com/)

Code:
        Activity.java

```
    webcam = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webcam);
    webcam.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webcam.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webcam.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webcam.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
         }
    }

    public void abrirurl(View view) {
         webcam.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.103:8080/stream_simple.html");
    }
```

Code: webcam.xml

```
 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webcam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cam1"
    android:text="@string/webcam"
    android:onClick="abrirurl" />
```

Comment: Where are you calling abrirurl(View view)?

Comment: At the xml, button onClick

Comment: Sorry, didn't see. If you put some other link, it doesn't open eather?

Comment: Didn't test it, i'll try when I get back home, in 1 hour or so.

Comment: It worked with other URL

Comment: What does `stream_simple.html` do?

Comment: Then this is solved, just find out why url is not working... (check url on browser)

Comment: I managed to solve it. WebView couldn't work with my stream. I had to change somethings, but now it's working. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

## Because in the url

```
http://192.168.0.103:8080    //is your system ip
```

and

```
stream_simple.html  // is your file which is in your system only.
```

when you run it on virtual device,which is in your system only will access the same file from system.
but when you run the same on the real device..it will not get your system ap as well this **stream_simple.html** file,which is in your system. thats y webview showing the blank page.

## solution

put **stream_simple.html**  file in assests folder of your android project.and then load it in webview will give you the desired output.

Comment: Actually, that is my Raspberry Pi Ip. And i can access it from my laptop (where the virtual device is). File isn't located at the laptop.